"find" function in Zabbix
Good afternoon.
I need to create a trigger to monitor the electrical voltage drop in my UPS.
The trigger makes measurements every 30 seconds. I need that within 5 minutes if the electricity drops to 0 twice in a row, the trigger should be triggered.
If not in a row, then just ignore it.
I tried using the "find" function in zabbix, I have server version 6.0.1, but I don't know how to make the right expression to make it work.
I tried this: find(/host/my_item_key(0,0,5m))=2
I tried to compose like this: find(/host/my_item_key,5m, "like", "error") - but I don't know the syntax here. I read the official documentation about this function "find" and about the operators of this function "like" "error". but I don't understand it completely.
